# Why is my image ignoring the size (height) of its containing element?

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have a `ul` of `img`s to create a side-scrolling gallery.

**I'd like for the images' height to be constrained to the browser window and their width to resize in order to maintain their scale.**

Even though I've specified a height for every containing element, the images with `height:90%;` are way bigger than the browser window. See the fiddle here: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jny0u3rc/)**

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional info: If I set `height: 90vh;` on `.gallery-image` it looks pretty much exactly how I want it, but it feels like a hack and I'd like to understand why % isn't working.

I'm looking to achieve this functionality: [example](http://wilderland.co/fashion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what your looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/jny0u3rc/11/

I simplified the code, this might not work if you have to have the images loaded in as list-items.

This specifies a container height of 100% and an image height of 90%. images are inline elements by default, so I set them to 
white-space:nowrap and overflow:auto on the container.

The CSS:

```
.gallery { 
height: 100%; 
overflow: auto; 
white-space: 
nowrap; }

.gallery img{
margin: 20px 10px 0 0px;
height:90%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/jny0u3rc/8/

```
.gallery {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 100%;
}

.gallery-list {
   list-style: none;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}

.gallery-listitem {
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   height: 100%;
   display:inline-block
 }
.gallery-image {
   height:90%;
   width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. You forgot to add 100% height on the html and body elements
2. You are using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`. The 100% height technique does not work on table displays. Change this to `display: block` and `display: inline-block` and you will get the expected results.

[**(Heavily) Modified Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/jny0u3rc/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by adding a width to each image. Of course the width doesn't have to be static. You can add a width of 100% and then set the height to auto so the images scale.

Comment: "I'd like for the images' height to be constrained to the browser window" - I don't believe your solution will do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. For a span to take a height, it has to be inline-block.
2. For an element to serve as offset parent (against which percentage heights of children are computed), it has to have `position` set. This is quite basic CSS.

See jsfiddle.net/6xh6wbpL/2.